# Database schema for two-player games

Tags: sql, database-schema

Let's have a game played by two players (or teams), where the outcome is represented by a score of both players (e.g. football). Is there an idiomatic way of storing results of such a game in a relational database?

I came up with two possible schemas, none of which seems to be universal enough.

**1. One row per game**

There will a table `games` with columns `game_id, winner, loser, winner_points, loser_points` and each game will be stored in one row of the table.

- This representation is great when one needs to iterate through all games.
- Computing statistics for a player is difficult (e.g. computing average number of points for a player)

**2. Two rows per game**

There will a `games` table with columns `game_id, player, opponent, player_points, opponent_points`. Each game will be stored in two rows of the table and they will have the same `game_id`.

- Iterating through all games is not trivial, but still easy
- Computing average points for a players is simple `SELECT AVG(player_points) FROM games WHERE player = some_player`
- Unfotunately the data in the table are now redundant

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest a better relational model with a games table, a player table and a third table to handle many-to-many relationship of players to games. Something like:

```
game( game_id, date, description, .... )
player( player_id, name, .... )
player_game( player_id, game_id, score )
```

Now you have a normalized (not redundant, etc.) schema that is very flexible.

To find he winner of a game you can:

```
select max(score), player_id from player_game where game_id = 'somegame'
```

To find total points for a player you can:

```
select sum(score) from player_game where player_id = 'someplayer'
```

And so on...

Comment: I'm trying to do something similar but with fighting events. Using your logic above sort of works:
Event (Event_ID (pk), Date,...)
Fighter (Fighter_ID (pk), Name...)
Fighter_Match(Fighter_ID (fk), Fight_ID, Outcome,...)
This seems like it would work for getting all fights from 1 fighter, but if I wanted to query all fights from a fighter and his/her opponent how would this be done? Seems like I would need another table?

Comment: @Jb. - Sorry for the delay seeing your message. I think you are right - the schema will work for you as you describe it, but I would stick to either "event" or "match" to keep things clear. The link for any two fighters is through a match, so you would do a query to find all matches where a fighter faced the same opponent.

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely do one row per score (i.e. 2 rows per game). I would store the player, and points, and if I wanted the opponent player/points, I'd look that up separately. I would almost certainly have a separate table for each game, which would mention things like when it was played, etc

No redundant data, everything is easy to gather etc.